# Are requests for help in coming up with plot details on topic, and how should I tag them?

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic

I'm creating an adventure for my game world and would like help coming up with specific details. Answers would necessarily be rather specific to the scenario (although system-agnostic and probably genre-flexible).

Is that on-topic in rpg.se? What sort of questions along this line are too broad or too narrow? What tag should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [adventure-writing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-writing). However, I don't think we get may questions of the form "please help me fill in the blank in my plot." These are probably at great risk of being unsuitable for our site, and the questions' suitability will be case by case. I'm not aware of any guidelines we have on how to make these questions work.

We don't necessarily do well coming up with ideas for your games, because questions requesting ideas generally fall under a lot of our bad subjective criteria from our [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help page:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about `______`”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain `______` to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)
>
> #### To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite `______`?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use `______` for `______`, what do you use?”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if `______` happened?”
> - *(a couple of these points skipped)*

If you come to us with a question saying: *"I have X circumstance. I need to do something. Does anyone have any ideas?"*, it's probably going to hit *most* of the negative points described above. A question like that is not a good fit for our site, and is probably better off asked on an RPG discussion forum or a chat room.

One basic requirement of our system is that questions should ideally have a single, objectively correct answer. Subjective questions (which comprise *a large portion* of our questions here) blur that requirement a bit, but you should still have requirements that allow us to objectively determine whether certain answers are *more valid and correct* than others. (If every answer is equally valid, voting becomes entirely subjective and our system breaks down in that question.)

So: make sure you have some specific criteria. Then, case by case, we'll work out what we can do.

Comment: I feel that per the aboves many questions under the gm-techniques and problem-players tags (and others) would be deemed as unfit for the site. Also true for system recommends. These are questions that do not have an objective true answer to them, but solicit ideas that the one who asked the question will ponder on, and select those that suit his specific or general needs, and others who read these and the answers may also find what they seek and get ideas, irrespective of the accepted answer. And this does not break the system, people seem to know that under these tags they may find such Q&As.

Comment: @Xabei You're right it affects system recommendations, which is why we have such strict requirements on absolutely every question and answer in the [[tag:game-recommendation]] tag (see the notice on each one). Problem-player and gm-techniques tags are less prone to this problem, as every answer is _not_ equally valid and these are usually Good Subjective questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the more "PC" but less intuitive [scenario-authoring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scenario-authoring).  I've tagged your Q with it.

Comment: That's a synonym to [adventure-writing]. (Though this does make me wonder why the main tag isn't [adventure-development].)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use [World Building Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) for questions related to building a new world. Questions about designing the world and environment are perfect for that site.

If your questions are about a specific gaming system (e.g. rules, creatures, and characters), or are about world-building elements unique to roleplaying, then they may be on topic here if they meet all of the other criteria for a good question, as discussd in the other answers.

Comment: I find this a reasonable recommendation. There's a lot of questions we *do* handle related to adventure writing, but World Building handles a lot of types of questions we *don't* — in particular idea generation, which we almost universally close as too broad or primarily opinion based.